# Broken CSV, how can I fix it?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV. I'd like to get it into a DB or just parse it with JavaScript, but either way fails due to the broken syntax. My entire CSV file is here:
https://gist.github.com/1023560

If you notice, it breaks where there are double quotes in the double quotes and it also fails when inserting into MySQL. The first break is seen at line 13. It breaks off and instead of returning the full:

```
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Portland-Community-Gardens/139244076118027?v=wall" target="_blank"><img src="/shared/cfm/image.cfm?id=348340" alt="Facebook" width="100" height="31" /></a>
```

It returns:

```
<a href="
```

For JavaScript I was going to just use CSVToArray() by Ben Nadel:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm

My ultimate goal tho is to put into MySQL so I can echo back a JSON feed with PHP's `json_encode()`.

Things I noticed that could be problematic are that double quotes can be in HTML tags like above, but also as the textNodes of HTML tags, so `"<span class="text">"Example"</span>"`

The first set of quotes is the CSV column, the 2nd are HTML quotes, and the third are text quotes.

Comment: The CSV file was generated poorly, i don't see any way to get around that (on import, don't know if you can generate a new CSV file)

Comment: It's not foolproof, but if this is a one-time thing you may be able to get away with using a regular expression to replace all quotes that are not the first character of a line and not preceded by a comma with whatever the escape character is (two quotes?).

Comment: The CSV wasn't generated which is the issue :\ It's saved from a hand written Excel file (I work for the government, and people don't like using "apps").

Comment: @kingjiv what would that regex look like?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: This could be done, but it would require a hybrid context-aware parser that was programmed to handle the special cases.  Unless you've got more than 50,000 lines of text to convert I'd suggest using a text editor with good regex support and fixing the data manually.

Comment: @yahelc: because the CSV he's trying to read isn't valid CSV, and any standard CSV parser will turn it into garbage or choke.

Comment: @Jim I'd do that, but Im not sure what the regex I'd need...

Comment: read the file line by line and make a table in the db with number of columns and simply loop insert the values

Comment: @Tomalak :) I work for Portland, we open as much data as possible: http://data.oregon.gov/ and this file is from: http://civicapps.org/ under Parks

Comment: @Oscar: Then what's the problem with "apps"?

Comment: @Tomalak We open all crime data, location data, and more. We even have http://pdxapi.com/ -- This is basically my entire job is to make the data accessible to developers as well as the public ;)

Comment: @Tomalak they like Word/Excel. If I tried to have them anything else (they even freaked when I suggested Google Docs) they'll flat out say no.

Comment: @Oscar: You'll need several, for each distinct situation. For example search `(<[^>]*")` replace `\1"` looks for a double-quote after `<` but with no intervening `>` and replaces it with the matched string plus an additional quote.  You'd have to run this multiple times until there were no more replacements.  Then there would be other situations that would require different treatment such as quotes inside XML text nodes.  BTW, the exact regex syntax will probably vary depending on the editor.

Comment: What are the "text quotes" that you speak of? If they are unnecessary, I'd definitely throw them out...but the real question is what you want to use the data for. If you're just going to put it on a webpage, is there any reason that you can't simply encode all non-alphanumeric characters? It's not the best solution, but it might work for your needs. _edit: Is Javascript the actual problem here? Could you avoid the problem by simply adding the values to your database using another method?

Answer (score 2):

You *may* be able to trick it and use a regex to look for:

```
"(.*?)"(?=,|$)
```

But that's kind of hack-ish (basically, only accept an end quote when immediately followed by a comma or an end of line). Same logic would apply to a find-replace. (Again, this all assumes that a "stray" quote will never follow standard CSV rules (e.g. have a comma/line [beginning/end] before or after it))

I assume you have no control over the original data and have to work with what you have?

**EDIT**

Though I've only tried this on a *small* sample of your data, this appears to find the "stray" quotes, to which you can use a replace with `""` on:

```
(?<!^|"|,)"(?!"|,|$)
```

Comment: @OscarGodson: I got it working about 90% of the way using the above replace. The big killer was your "In 1900, the area along the..." entry has exceptions. I feel like hand-editing a couple entries may not be the end of the world, though.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes don't matter as much as the commas do.  If comma is the delimiter, then you can't have commas in the values.  If you can get the CSV saved using a different delimter, you might get better results.
Use a character like ~ or a ^ instead of a comma as the delimiter.

Comment: I don't think the delimiter is the problem here - it's Javascript parsing the quotes, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are either on Windows or can do this on a Windows box, check out [Logparser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logparser). It is a free command line utility that can parse many data formats including CSV, and can output to many formats including SQL.